# "No query results for model [App\Shop\Categories\Category] 1"

Tags: laravel

[No query results for model app\shop\categories\category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTmZE.png)

Comment: explain your question and problem clearly

Comment: post related code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got `App\Shop\Categories\Category::find(1);` somewhere in your code but you don't have a Category in your database with the id of 1.